# Directus 9, how can I set permissions on Files?

Tags: directus, headless-cms

I have an App with private messages, the messages are stored in a directus collections, each item has multiple Attachments (files).
How can I restrict access to these files for other users, that are not in the Conversation?

I have tried set up a usergroup for each conversation, but I think its not the best way to do it.

And another question, how can I set the "mine" permission on files?

Answer (score 3):

1. From setting menu -> roles and permissions
2. Select public roles then system collections
3. At files collection allow public to view permission

Now any public user can download your file.

```
https://your-directus.com/assets/<file-id>?download
```